# What live distro can automatically accept usb tethering from android phone?

Tags: live-usb, livecd, connection-sharing

I want to take my old notebook while travelling. I have to boot up only from usb or cd though. I want to connect to the internet using usb tethering from my android phone (HTC Desire + cyanogen mod 7.1)

If connect my android phone to my Windows 7 computer via usb cable and turn usb tethering on Windows does the rest and I am connect to the Internet.

Can I be **autoconnected** (usb tethering preferably) to the **internet** using any live usb/cd linux/unix distro? Which one?

I'll be creating the usb from Windows7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NetworkManager can connect you automatically if it's configured to do so. And it comes with most modern distros, such as Fedora or Ubuntu. I recommend using live USB so that you can retain the configuration between boots.

Comment: Is there any `Ubuntu from USB` file I can download? Something like slax? I didn't manage to get internet from slax...

Comment: Or I have to go through all these steps? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick

Comment: Dunno. I don't do Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I use Xubuntu 16.04, and I find that it allows USB tethering from my Android device out of the box, no configuration needed. That is, I connect the Android device through USB, turn on USB tethering on the Android device, and the computer is online almost instantly. This also works when booting from a live USB.

I suspect that this should also hold true for nearly any other modern Ubuntu based distro, and possibly even most modern GNU/Linux distros.